# POST PHP and javascript data using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I apologize if this is a duplicate question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere else.

I have a page where users are able to see all of their submissions with each one in a separate row. There is an "X" that, when users click it, I want that row to be deleted in the database.

Here is the function that I have (jQuery) that triggers when the user clicks the "X"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete").click(function(e){
        var id = e.target.id;
        $("#"+id + "_row").hide('slow');
        //Need to POST the id variable to PHP file.
    });
});
```

How would I post the ID variable to a php file that would then run the mySQL query on the database?

Comment: You already answered the question in your title: AJAX, e.g: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.post('/some-file.php', {id: e.target.id});`

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete").click(function(e){
        var id = e.target.id;
        $("#"+id + "_row").hide('slow');
        $.ajax({
            url: "path/to/php/file",
            dataType: "json",
            method: "POST",
            data: { target: e.target.id },
            success: function(data) {
                // do something with the data passed back by the PHP script.
            }
    });
});
```

Parameters:

> url: self explanatory
>
> dataType: the kind of data you're expecting to
> get from the PHP script
>
> method: http method which you'll use for your
> request
>
> data: data you'll be passing to the PHP, since we're using
> POST in this case. If you were using GET, you can set variables in the
> "url:" field just like you would on any other url.
>
> success: what
> happens when the request succeeds.